# Bulk Inserts SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm curious if anyone can suggest a better way to do bulk inserts. At my current job we are constructing xml strings that are passed as variables to a stored procedure then creating a temp table and inserting the xml. A lot of time I see a cursor being used which I prefer not to do if possible

```
DECLARE @DriverToImport TABLE 
        (DriverId INT NULL DEFAULT (0),
         IsNew TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
         DriverExternalId NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
         DriverName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
         HireDate SMALLDATETIME NULL,
         HomeNumber NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
         CellNumber NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
         DriverTypeId INT NOT NULL,
         ISDId INT NOT NULL,
         CreatedBy NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
         DtCreated SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
         LastUpdatedBy NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
         DtLastUpdated SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
         PINCode NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
         UNIQUE (DriverExternalId)
    )

INSERT INTO @DriverToImport (DriverExternalId, DriverName, HireDate, HomeNumber, CellNumber, DriverTypeId, ISDId, CreatedBy, DtCreated, LastUpdatedBy, DtLastUpdated, PINCode)
    SELECT
        T.c.value('./Id[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)'),
        T.c.value('./Fn[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') + ', ' + T.c.value('./Ln[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') + ' ' + T.c.value('./Mn[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
        T.c.value('./HireDate[1]', 'SMALLDATETIME'),
        T.c.value('./HomeNumber[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)'),
        T.c.value('./CellNumber[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)'),
        (SELECT dt.DriverTypeId
         FROM DriverType dt
         WHERE dt.DriverTypeName LIKE '%' + T.c.value('./DriverType[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)') + '%'),
        @ISDId, @UserName, @dtCurrent, @UserName, @dtCurrent,
        T.c.value('./PinCode[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)')
    FROM 
        @xmlDoc.nodes('/Drivers/Driver') T (c)
    WHERE 
        (T.c.value('./Id[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)') IS NOT NULL)
        AND (T.c.value('./Id[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)') <> '')

DECLARE newDriverCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT
        t.DriverExternalId, t.DriverName, t.HireDate,
        t.HomeNumber, t.CellNumber, t.DriverTypeId,
        t.CreatedBy, t.DtCreated, t.LastUpdatedBy, t.DtLastUpdated,
        t.PINCode
    FROM
        @DriverToImport t
    WHERE 
        (t.IsNew = 1)

OPEN newDriverCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM newDriverCursor INTO @DriverId, @DriverName, @HireDate, @HomeNumber, @CellNumber, @DriverTypeId, @CreatedBy, @DtCreated, @LastUpdatedBy, @DtLastUpdated, @PINCode

WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Driver (DriverExternalId, DriverName, EmployeeNumber, HireDate, HomeNumber, CellNumber, DriverTypeId, ISDId, CreatedBy, DtCreated, LastUpdatedBy, DtLastUpdated, PINCode, IsActive, ResetPIN)
    VALUES (@DriverExternalId, @DriverName, @DriverExternalId, @HireDate, @HomeNumber, @CellNumber, @DriverTypeId, @ISDId, @CreatedBy, @DtCreated, @LastUpdatedBy, @DtLastUpdated, @PINCode, 1, 0)
END
```

I know in the past I've used a merge statements with a SQL variable to do bulk inserts. Which works well too, but requires a table variable to be created for each one. So my question is in SQL Server 2016 is there a more robust way to handle bulk inserts ?

Comment: You should use CTEs or merge statements.  Avoid cursors... Even if someone holds a gun on you don't use cursors :P

Comment: I don't see any cursor in this, BTW, what is wrong with a simple INSERT INTO statement?

Comment: It does I just spared yall the entirety of the procedure - Updated to include more of the SPROC - I Agree I dont like using them either , but in order to do that I need  to present a viable alternative - Looking into CTEs

Comment: The reason a simple insert statement would not work is that on some procedures we are providing detailed feedback for each row update/insert attempt. So in these cases logic is applied to each pass to update a temp log table. It these cases I've no clue how to avoid using a cursor - SQL is not my strong suite :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "bulk insert" is fairly ambiguous, so it kind of depends on what you mean.  Based on your description it sounds like you might want to look at Table Valued Parameters from both the [SQL Server side](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) and from the [.Net Framework side](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx). The old method of passing an XML string or delimited string directly to a stored procedure and doing the XML shredding in the stored procedure is essentially what TVPs were intended to replace. Conceptually what it does is allow you to submit a .Net DataTable as a parameter to a stored procedure whole-hog.

However, I can think of other meanings of bulk insert as well. There's the [SqlBulkCopy class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx), which allows you to insert a DataTable as a single step fairly efficiently. There's also the [BULK INSERT SQL statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), which is primarily intended for loading CSV files. Additionally, there's SSIS, which is a full ETL package. If you need more logic than BULK INSERT allows or need to do additional mapping, some have used SSIS to accomplish that between systems.

So, like I said, it kind of depends on what you mean by "bulk insert".

Comment: This is exactly the info I needed - Thanks :)